# StartSonar.bat command not found

Tags: sonarqube, devops

Sonarqube and sonar scanner installed on ubuntu
Trying to start sonar on terminal in dir /home/vedant_shukla/Desktop/sonarqube-8.5.1.38104/bin/linux-x86-64 using command StartSonar.bat
Showing StartSonar.bat: command not found
Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

.bat files work on windows CMD/terminal. For Linux/Ubuntu file should be sonar.sh